# Unit testing lambda script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, boto3

I wrote a lambda script to manage the life cycle of Amazon Machine Images using python and boto3. The script is working fine, but when I realized that I had to write unit tests for it, my nightmare began. I am not a develop and I am used to write scripts as SysAdmin.

I have already created unit tests for functions with return state like the following below and I works fine.

```
def get_interface_wrapper(region, service, interface_type):
    interface_types = ['client', 'resource']
    interface = None

    if (type(region) == str) and (type(service) == str) and (type(interface_type) == str) and (interface_type in interface_types):
        interface = ("boto3." + interface_type +
                     "(" + "service_name=service," + "region_name=region)")

    return interface

def get_interface(region, service, interface_type):
    return eval(get_interface_wrapper(region, service, interface_type))

#Unit tests
def test_get_interface_client(self):

    service = 'ec2'
    interface_expression = 'boto3.client(service_name=service,region_name=region)'
    client_interface = get_interface_wrapper(
        self.region, service, 'client')
    self.assertEqual(client_interface, interface_expression)


def test_get_interface_resource(self):

    service = 'ec2'
    interface_expression = 'boto3.resource(service_name=service,region_name=region)'
    resource_interface = get_interface_wrapper(
        self.region, service, 'resource')
    self.assertEqual(resource_interface, interface_expression)
```

However, for the following functions that have no return statement and rely on AWS endpoint, I am struggling to wrap my head around it. How I can a mock the endpoint or how I can change my code to create a unit test that does not rely on AWS endpoints.

```
def update_states(actions, ec2_client, logs_client, log_group, log_stream, dryrun_enabled=True):
    for action in actions:

        action.update({'phase': 'planning', 'PlanningTime': datetime.utcnow(
        ).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'})
        put_log_events(logs_client, log_group, log_stream, [action])

        # The tag packer_ami_state_tagging_date is not set
        if (action['is_timestamp_present'] == True):

            if (action['action'] == 'update'):
                # The tag packer_ami_state_tagging_date is set, so update the state and tagging date
                try:

                    ec2_client.Image(action['ImageId']).create_tags(DryRun=dryrun_enabled, Tags=[{'Key': 'packer_ami_state', 'Value': action['new_packer_ami_state']},
                                                                                                 {'Key': 'packer_ami_state_tagging_date', 'Value': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'}, ])

                    operation_result = [
                        {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime':  datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'Result': 'AMI state and tagging date was updated'}, ]

                except Exception as e:

                    operation_result = [
                        {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime': (datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'), 'Result': 'AMI state and tagging date was not updated', 'Error': e.args[0], }]

                finally:
                    put_log_events(logs_client, log_group,
                                   log_stream, operation_result)

            if (action['action'] == 'delete'):
                image = ec2_client.Image(action['ImageId'])
                snapshots = []
                for blockDevMapping in image.block_device_mappings:
                    if 'Ebs' in blockDevMapping:
                        snapshots.append(blockDevMapping['Ebs']['SnapshotId'])

                try:
                    image.deregister(DryRun=dryrun_enabled)
                    operation_result = [
                        {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime':  datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'Result': 'AMI was deregistered'}, ]

                except Exception as e:
                    operation_result = [
                        {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime': (datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'), 'Result': 'AMI was not deregistered', 'Error': e.args[0], }]

                finally:
                    put_log_events(logs_client, log_group,
                                   log_stream, operation_result)

                counter = 1
                for snapshotID in snapshots:
                    snapshot = ec2_client.Snapshot(snapshotID)

                    try:
                        snapshot.delete(DryRun=dryrun_enabled)
                        operation_result = [
                            {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime':  datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'Result': 'SnapShot deleted', 'SnapShotID': snapshotID}, ]

                    except Exception as e:
                        operation_result = [
                            {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime': (datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'), 'Result': 'SnapShot not deleted', 'Error': e.args[0], 'SnapShotID': snapshotID}, ]

                    finally:
                        put_log_events(logs_client, log_group,
                                       log_stream, operation_result)

                    counter += 1

            if (action['action'] == 'none'):
                action.update(
                    {'OperationDate': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'OperationResult': 'No action'})

                operation_result = [
                    {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime':  datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'Result': 'No action'}, ]

                put_log_events(logs_client, log_group,
                               log_stream, operation_result)

        else:
            try:
                ec2_client.Image(action['ImageId']).create_tags(DryRun=dryrun_enabled, Tags=[
                    {'Key': 'packer_ami_state_tagging_date', 'Value': datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'}, ])

                operation_result = [
                    {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime':  datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z', 'Result': 'Tag created'}, ]

            except Exception as e:
                operation_result = [
                    {'phase': 'execution', 'imageid': action['ImageId'], 'ExecutionTime': (datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'), 'Result': 'Tag not created', 'Error': e.args[0], }]

            finally:
                put_log_events(logs_client, log_group,
                               log_stream, operation_result)


def put_log_events(client, log_group_name, log_stream_name, log_events):
    log_stream = client.describe_log_streams(
        logGroupName=log_group_name,
        logStreamNamePrefix=log_stream_name
    )

    if (bool(log_stream['logStreams'])) and ('uploadSequenceToken' in log_stream['logStreams'][0]):
        response = {
            'nextSequenceToken': log_stream['logStreams'][0]['uploadSequenceToken']}
    else:
        response = {}

    for log_event in log_events:
        if bool(response):
            response = client.put_log_events(
                logGroupName=log_group_name,
                logStreamName=log_stream_name,
                logEvents=[
                    {
                        'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
                        'message': json.dumps(log_event)
                    },
                ],
                sequenceToken=response['nextSequenceToken']
            )
        else:
            response = client.put_log_events(
                logGroupName=log_group_name,
                logStreamName=log_stream_name,
                logEvents=[
                    {
                        'timestamp': int(round(time.time() * 1000)),
                        'message': json.dumps(log_event)
                    },
                ],
            )
```

Comment: You should split `update_states` in small functions that do only one things, from there unitest will be much easier. So focus on refactoring your code first.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use patching in the built-in [unittest.mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).  I use that to mock out all boto3 calls so I never hit a real AWS service.  There are many options, but here is a simple example that mocks out the client.

Suppose you have code in a module named "my_code" that imports boto3 and makes calls to a "ssm" boto3 client to the get_parameters_by_path function.  You might mock that out with code such as this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
```

...

```
@patch('my_app.my_code.boto3')
def test_secrets_load_ssm(self, mock_boto):
    mock_client = MagicMock()
    mock_boto.client.return_value = mock_client
    mock_client.get_parameters_by_path.return_value = helper_function()

    my_param = my_code.my_function_being_tested_that_fetches_a_parameter('/TEST_APP/CI/secure_string_test')

    self.assertEqual(my_param, 'secure string value')


def helper_function():
    return {'Parameters': [{'Name': '/TEST_APP/CI/secure_string_test',
                            'Type': 'SecureString',
                            'Value': 'secure string value',
                            'Version': 1,
                            'LastModifiedDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 8, 14, 44, 26, 878000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
                            'ARN': 'arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:999478573200:parameter/TEST_APP/CI/secure_string_test'}], ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'b9f016a4-485d-80d2-a504-015d081d8603',
                                 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
                                 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'b9f016a4-475d-40d2-a504-015d981d8603',
                                                 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
                                                 'content-length': '666',
                                                 'date': 'Fri, 30 Aug 2019 16:57:17 GMT'},
                                 'RetryAttempts': 0}
            }
```

I put the mocked-up return value in a separate helper function since that is not the point of this example and be whatever JSON you need boto3 to mock-up as a return.  If you aren't familiar with unittest mock and patching you'll have to ramp a bit on using it, but having done so myself I can attest that it will solve these kinds of boto3 unit test problems much more elegantly.

The `@patch` annotation lets you swap out the real boto3 library with mock-up calls you create.  The annotation declares which imported function you are patching, and that requires a corresponding variable in the function signature (`mock_boto` in this example).  The next couple line that set up an object to be returned when the code in the function I am testing calls boto3.client(), and then the following line sets up what should be returned when the code calls the get_parameters_by_path function of the client object.  Patching has functions like `assert_called_once` on your mocks to validate that the function was called as expected, so even if the function doesn't return anything you can mock it out.

Comment: Shawn, thank you for your replay. I will test your idea a let you know.